# Intermittent internet connection/DNS issues with Debian

Tags: networking, networkmanager, internet, router, connectivity

For the last 15~20 days I've faced a inconsistent connection issues. I've tried several things, and mostly I can't say if they helped or not.

What I can say for sure:

- When returning from hibernation, although I'm still connected to the WIFI, I can't access anything on the internet.
- Chrome returns `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, changing browsers doesn't solve the issue.
- Disconnecting and connecting again, doesn't help either.
- The command `sudo dhclient -v` solves the problem, when it works. (Details bellow)
- It's not my ISP, as internet still works in my desktop and smartphone (connected to the same wifi). [but maybe is a router/modem issue?]

Those are the weird details:

- **Sometimes** I can still ping sites, but can't access them and **sometimes** ping doesn't work, and it returns `connect: Network is unreachable`.
- Rebooting **sometimes** solves the problem, sometimes doesn't.
- **Sometimes** the problem solved it self, with me doing nothing.
- The first couple times this issue happened I've tried changing the DNS from AUTO to Manual (8.8.8.8) or the other way around, depending how I left the last time. It seemed to work, but now it doesn't, so maybe it never did anything to solve the issue and the issue solved it self?

As I said, running `sudo dhclient -v` solves the problem when the return finishes like this:

> DHCPACK of 192.168.15.4 from 192.168.15.1
>
> bound to 192.168.15.4 -- renewal in 17437 seconds.

However, **sometimes**, when I run the command it returns this:

> No DHCPOFFERS received.
>
> No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.

And the problem persists.

## Bellow are the returns of some commands that might help with diagnostics:

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

**ifconfig**

```
command not found
```

**ip route show**

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev br-7905315c0c67 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-7905315c0c67 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-bb285dfa325a proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
```

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:2a:72:c0:da:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.8.72/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link enp3s0f1:avahi
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:86:f2:cc:95:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.15.4/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 42972sec preferred_lft 42972sec
    inet6 2804:7f2:2980:fa68:50c4:6476:6282:be9/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43168sec preferred_lft 43168sec
    inet6 fe80::1d23:31f:b217:e60d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b9:59:21:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-7905315c0c67: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ca:dc:1a:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-7905315c0c67
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-bb285dfa325a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:45:ee:9f:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-bb285dfa325a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**dhclient -v WHEN IT DOESN'T WORK**

```
Listening on LPF/br-bb285dfa325a/02:42:45:ee:9f:bd
Sending on   LPF/br-bb285dfa325a/02:42:45:ee:9f:bd
Listening on LPF/br-7905315c0c67/02:42:ca:dc:1a:34
Sending on   LPF/br-7905315c0c67/02:42:ca:dc:1a:34
Listening on LPF/docker0/02:42:b9:59:21:ea
Sending on   LPF/docker0/02:42:b9:59:21:ea
Listening on LPF/wlp2s0/80:86:f2:cc:95:7f
Sending on   LPF/wlp2s0/80:86:f2:cc:95:7f
Listening on LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:c0:da:1d
Sending on   LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:c0:da:1d
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.15.4 from 192.168.15.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

**dhclient -v WHEN IT DOES WORK**

```
Listening on LPF/br-bb285dfa325a/02:42:3a:6c:f8:53
Sending on   LPF/br-bb285dfa325a/02:42:3a:6c:f8:53
Listening on LPF/br-7905315c0c67/02:42:a9:2c:f1:4d
Sending on   LPF/br-7905315c0c67/02:42:a9:2c:f1:4d
Listening on LPF/docker0/02:42:47:5b:95:10
Sending on   LPF/docker0/02:42:47:5b:95:10
Listening on LPF/wlp2s0/80:86:f2:cc:95:7f
Sending on   LPF/wlp2s0/80:86:f2:cc:95:7f
Listening on LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:c0:da:1d
Sending on   LPF/enp3s0f1/b8:2a:72:c0:da:1d
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on br-7905315c0c67 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on br-bb285dfa325a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.4 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.15.4 from 192.168.15.1
bound to 192.168.15.4 -- renewal in 17437 seconds.
```

## >> EDIT

After @Fubar answer I did a `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and noticed the a lot of warnings of *Possible missing firmware*. [image] Not sure it ever happened before (if it did, never noticed) or if it's related. After that I haven't been able to reproduce the issue, which might be a good thing, as long it doesn't "come back".

Comment: Is this an issue that's only changed recently, and return from hibernation was fine prior to a certain date?  If so, did something happen recently in the way of upgrades?  System update, software updates, etc?

Comment: I had some internet issues a couple months ago (working in office), but just a few times so I didn't even investigated. Since I started work from home this became a regular issue, so maybe there is a connection here. There's definitely been system updates,  before and after the issue, but I don't think the issue started just after a update, or maybe I just didn't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely has more to do with the drivers involved than with the OS.  Coming out of hibernation in Windows, for instance, is managed by the OS, but actually accomplished by the other software bits like drivers.  If the drivers don't handle waking correctly, there can be inconsistency in how well it works.  I'd suggest, as a test, when you next have the issue, use `lspci` or somesuch to figure out your driver's name, then `lsmod` to see if it's loaded as a module, rather than built into the kernel.  If so, you can try unloading with `rmmod` or `modprobe -r` and then reloading with `modprobe`.  The module you're interested in, judging from the info provided above, is the r8168 driver which is the official RealTek driver.  There may be dependencies with the module, so you may need to play around a bit to make sure that you get all the right modules, though networking probably has dependencies now than when I was working with it.  Once you get all the bits sorted, you can create a shell script which executes all of the commands you used, then run it whenever you have an issue, rather than trying to remember the sequence every time.  All of this, including any shell script, will obviously need to be run as root or using sudo.

Not positive that this will work, of course, but it may help.  You can also [check here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) to obtain the latest firmware for your adapter to ensure that it's up to date.  If it isn't, updating it may also help with the issue.  Just a few places to look.

Comment: Thank you. Can you take a look at the recent edit I added to the post? The image does reference r8168.

Comment: It would seem that the driver code must handle a number of different RTL species.  As the "r8168" doesn't show up in warning, I'd assume that the firmware was available for that board.  Hopefully the update will have taken care of the issue.  As I mentioned, this smells like much more of a driver/firmware thing than an OS specific one.  Hope the issue stays away for you.